# Creating An Image Download Chrome Extension

Tags: image, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, download

I am creating a chrome extension that downloads all the images on the current webpage and this is what I have

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('checkPage');
  checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

downloadImages()

  }, false);
}, false);

function downloadImages() {







var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var srcList = [];
var i = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    if(images.length > i){
        srcList.push(images[i].src);
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.id=i;
        link.download = images[i].src;
        link.href = images[i].src;
        link.click();
        i++;
    }
},1500);









}
```

This adds a click listener that should download all images when you click the button on the other section. I know this code works because I replaced the code that downloads the images with the code for an alert and when I pressed the button it indeed made an alert, *so why is it that when I add the image downloading code it doesn't do anything?* Also I have tested the image downloading code, it works.

Comment: The download attribute only works for same-origin URLs. You'll have to use chrome.downloads API. The file name in download attribute should be valid but you're assigning an URL which contains slashes, colons and other invalid characters. Those are replaced with underscores automatically though. Anyway, you should debug the content script in devtools instead of guessing and using alerts.

Comment: yes, debug it. i also think faking a click without a previous user action (forgotten after interval) wont be accepted by the browser.